# Book with nano/biotech, maze/labyrinth, prisoners

Tags: story-identification, books, nanotechnology

I'm looking for some help identifying a book I read 10 - 15 years ago. I know this is probably a long shot, but extensive keyword searching Google bears no fruit.

The story is about a group of people who are taken prisoner (I think for political reasons) by the government and experimented on. They're augmented by nano or bio tech and put into a maze. The maze is pretty deadly and they have to use their new augmentations to survive. This was for observational purposes. Lots of people die, whether through the maze or augmentation issues.

I do remember that the prisoners referred to themselves as 'lab rats,' and those that did survive eventually died from what was done to them. The cover was dark, but I don't remember what type of image.